# How to scrape text data from a website that requires password

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, lxml

I am trying to crawl the body text from this website "https://seekingalpha.com/article/4414009-jupai-holdings-limited-jp-ceo-jianda-ni-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript". However, to view the full article it requires a login. I am lost at how I'm supposed to get past that and then scrape the data. I've used other tools such as bs4 but here is what I have for now.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

login_info = {
    "email": "<USER NAME>",
    "password": "<PASSWORD>",
}

session_requests = requests.session()

login_url = "https://seekingalpha.com/"

result = session_requests.get(login_url)

tree = html.fromstring(result.text)

result = session_requests.post(
    login_url,
    data = login_info,
    headers = dict(referer=login_url)
)

url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/article/4414009-jupai-holdings-limited-jp-ceo-jianda-ni-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript'
result = session_requests.get(
    url,
    headers = dict(referer = url)
)

tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
```

How do I crawl such text files from websites like these that require accounts? (* you can create a free account to test it out)

Comment: When you login, they will return a cookie that identifies you to their site.  You need to send that cookie back with and further requests.  You'll have to check the headers that are returned to know which cookie it is.

Comment: @TimRoberts how do I check the headers? Sorry, completely new to this.

Comment: Also, in most tutorials, they had a convenient "/login" page. But this one doesn't.

Comment: Actually, `requests.session` is supposed to manage the cookies for you.  Have you checked the HTML of that page to know how to submit a login?

Comment: @TimRoberts from my understanding, they don't have a html page written for it. It was a "onClick" JS event. So I'm not sure how to access that.

Comment: Ah, their "Sign In" button brings up a dialog that allows Google ID or Apple ID.  It is quite possible you will have to use Selenium for this.  Selenium actually runs the Chrome browser, and lets you generate click events.  It's more work than `requests`, but helps with dynamic web sites because it has a Javascript interpreter.

Comment: Pay attention it's `requests.Session()` not `session()` where the `S` is capital letter